# Pandas: conditional counting when multiple conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
                      dtm        f           C      A   B
0   2018-03-01 00:00:00 +0000   50.135  9.000000    0   0
1   2018-03-01 00:00:01 +0000   50.130  9.000000    0   0
2   2018-03-01 00:00:02 +0000   50.120  9.000000    0   0
3   2018-03-01 00:00:03 +0000   50.112  9.000000    0   0
4   2018-03-01 00:00:04 +0000   50.102  9.000000    0   0
5   2018-03-01 00:00:05 +0000   50.097  9.000000    0   0
6   2018-03-01 00:00:06 +0000   11.095  9.000000    0   0
7   2018-03-01 00:00:07 +0000   11.095  9.000000    0   0
8   2018-03-01 00:00:08 +0000   11.092  9.000000    0   0
9   2018-03-01 00:00:09 +0000   11.095  9.000000    0   0
10  2018-03-01 00:00:10 +0000   11.097  5.000000    0   0
11  2018-03-01 00:00:11 +0000   11.097  5.000000    0   0
12  2018-03-01 00:00:12 +0000   11.097  5.000000    0   0
13  2018-03-01 00:00:13 +0000   50.100  5.000000    0   0
14  2018-03-01 00:00:14 +0000   50.102  5.000000    0   0
15  2018-03-01 00:00:15 +0000   50.105  5.000000    0   0
16  2018-03-01 00:00:16 +0000   50.102  5.000000    0   0
17  2018-03-01 00:00:17 +0000   50.102  5.000000    0   0
```

A and B are two Counters that work like this:

- if((f>=50) or (f<50 & C<8)) then A increase by 1
- if f<50 and C>8 then B increase by 1

the expected outcome should be like:

```
                      dtm           f         C     A   B
0   2018-03-01 00:00:00 +0000   50.135  9.000000    0   0
1   2018-03-01 00:00:01 +0000   50.130  9.000000    1   0
2   2018-03-01 00:00:02 +0000   50.120  9.000000    2   0
3   2018-03-01 00:00:03 +0000   50.112  9.000000    3   0
4   2018-03-01 00:00:04 +0000   50.102  9.000000    4   0
5   2018-03-01 00:00:05 +0000   50.097  9.000000    5   0
6   2018-03-01 00:00:06 +0000   11.095  9.000000    5   1
7   2018-03-01 00:00:07 +0000   11.095  9.000000    5   2   
8   2018-03-01 00:00:08 +0000   11.092  9.000000    5   3
9   2018-03-01 00:00:09 +0000   11.095  9.000000    5   4
10  2018-03-01 00:00:10 +0000   11.097  5.000000    6   4
11  2018-03-01 00:00:11 +0000   11.097  5.000000    7   4
12  2018-03-01 00:00:12 +0000   11.097  5.000000    8   4
13  2018-03-01 00:00:13 +0000   50.100  5.000000    9   4
14  2018-03-01 00:00:14 +0000   50.102  5.000000    10  4
15  2018-03-01 00:00:15 +0000   50.105  5.000000    11  4
16  2018-03-01 00:00:16 +0000   50.102  5.000000    12  4
17  2018-03-01 00:00:17 +0000   50.102  5.000000    13  4
```

Please notice that when a A increases B keeps its value, and the other way around. They do not reset. Any idea about that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me working nice subtracting `1` with [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) and for removing possible `-1` in first rows add [`clip_lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_lower.html):

```
m1 = (df.f >=50) | ((df.f<50) & (df.C<8))
m2 = (df.f<50) & (df.C>8)

df['A'] = m1.cumsum().sub(1).clip_lower(0)
df['B'] = m2.cumsum().sub(1).clip_lower(0)
```

Comment: @jezrael, exccellent answer, may I know why there is a change in your output, and the expected output in question. there is no '4' in your df['B']

Answer (score 5):

#### Assumptions

- `df.C > 8` was meant to be `df.C >= 8` because that would be the compliment to `df.C < 8`
- `(df.f < 50) & (df.C < 8)` isn't necessary because of the `or` statement and `df.f >= 50` on the other side of it.
- Column `'A'` starting with `0` seems to be a weird thing that needs special handling.  It would be cleaner to assume that it begins with zero and starts incrementing at the first `True`

---

#### In line with `assign`

```
a = df.f.values >= 50
b = df.C.values < 8
c = a | b

df.assign(A=c.cumsum(), B=(~c).cumsum())

                          dtm       f    C   A  B
0   2018-03-01 00:00:00 +0000  50.135  9.0   1  0
1   2018-03-01 00:00:01 +0000  50.130  9.0   2  0
2   2018-03-01 00:00:02 +0000  50.120  9.0   3  0
3   2018-03-01 00:00:03 +0000  50.112  9.0   4  0
4   2018-03-01 00:00:04 +0000  50.102  9.0   5  0
5   2018-03-01 00:00:05 +0000  50.097  9.0   6  0
6   2018-03-01 00:00:06 +0000  11.095  9.0   6  1
7   2018-03-01 00:00:07 +0000  11.095  9.0   6  2
8   2018-03-01 00:00:08 +0000  11.092  9.0   6  3
9   2018-03-01 00:00:09 +0000  11.095  9.0   6  4
10  2018-03-01 00:00:10 +0000  11.097  5.0   7  4
11  2018-03-01 00:00:11 +0000  11.097  5.0   8  4
12  2018-03-01 00:00:12 +0000  11.097  5.0   9  4
13  2018-03-01 00:00:13 +0000  50.100  5.0  10  4
14  2018-03-01 00:00:14 +0000  50.102  5.0  11  4
15  2018-03-01 00:00:15 +0000  50.105  5.0  12  4
16  2018-03-01 00:00:16 +0000  50.102  5.0  13  4
17  2018-03-01 00:00:17 +0000  50.102  5.0  14  4
```

---

#### In place

```
a = df.f.values >= 50
b = df.C.values < 8
c = a | b

df[['A', 'B']] = np.column_stack([c, ~c]).cumsum(0)
df
```

---

#### Reduced

```
c = (df.f.values >= 50) | (df.C.values < 8)

df.assign(A=c.cumsum(), B=(~c).cumsum())
```

---

#### With special handling

```
a = df.f.values >= 50
b = df.C.values < 8
c0 = a | b
c1 = ~c0

c0[0] = False
c1[0] = False

df.assign(A=c0.cumsum(), B=c1.cumsum())

                          dtm       f    C   A  B
0   2018-03-01 00:00:00 +0000  50.135  9.0   0  0
1   2018-03-01 00:00:01 +0000  50.130  9.0   1  0
2   2018-03-01 00:00:02 +0000  50.120  9.0   2  0
3   2018-03-01 00:00:03 +0000  50.112  9.0   3  0
4   2018-03-01 00:00:04 +0000  50.102  9.0   4  0
5   2018-03-01 00:00:05 +0000  50.097  9.0   5  0
6   2018-03-01 00:00:06 +0000  11.095  9.0   5  1
7   2018-03-01 00:00:07 +0000  11.095  9.0   5  2
8   2018-03-01 00:00:08 +0000  11.092  9.0   5  3
9   2018-03-01 00:00:09 +0000  11.095  9.0   5  4
10  2018-03-01 00:00:10 +0000  11.097  5.0   6  4
11  2018-03-01 00:00:11 +0000  11.097  5.0   7  4
12  2018-03-01 00:00:12 +0000  11.097  5.0   8  4
13  2018-03-01 00:00:13 +0000  50.100  5.0   9  4
14  2018-03-01 00:00:14 +0000  50.102  5.0  10  4
15  2018-03-01 00:00:15 +0000  50.105  5.0  11  4
16  2018-03-01 00:00:16 +0000  50.102  5.0  12  4
17  2018-03-01 00:00:17 +0000  50.102  5.0  13  4
```